# Getting error: "PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource : The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object."

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

While running PowerShell script as

```
Register-PSRepository -Name XYZ -SourceLocation https://urlname/api/v3
```

I get error:

> ```
> PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource : The property 'Name' cannot
> be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
> ```

Why I'm getting this issue?

Comment: On One of my servers I'm getting similar Problem 
I've accidentaly removed PSGallery source, when I try to add it back I get
    ` Register-PSRepository -Default
    PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource : The property 
    'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
    property exists.`

Comment: @Tomek I fixed that issue by firstly unregistered PSRepository and then tried to registered. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do not have any Repository registered on that machine right now 
 Get-PSRepository
WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.

Comment: @Tomek please run Get-PSRepository and if you found your modules already listed then unregistered

Comment: Yeah :) Get-Psrepository says: WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.